# Weird behavior of custom UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, subclass

I have subclassed UINavigationBar so I can create a gradient to fill it. My problem is that when I present the Navigation Controller, while it animates from bottom to the top, the color of the button items on the navigation bar is still blue (the default one) and it only changes as it should when it finishes animating (when the Navigation Controller reaches the top). I have attached to pictures two help you understand what my problem is.

[image]

[image]

Comment: where do you change the colors? put your code

Comment: I think  button color change method you use outside of animation.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever figure out a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You put your change color code in animated method only so both together doing fine try this.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintcolor:[uicolor red color]];
[self.navigationController.navigationbaritem same code here only
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I am changing the colors in drawRect, in the subclass of UINavigationBar. This is the only way I can add the gradient to it.

Comment: your all changes of navigation bar should be in animation method only.I think your Bar Button color change is out of animation method